# Xcode 7 can't find details about which line or which method crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

How to recognize a place where app crashes. I've tried add All Exception break point. I've tried to search for rangeOfCharacterFromSet, but there is no places where it really crashes.

```
2016-10-13 15:18:29.809 Dev[11794:809091] -[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5dae398
2016-10-13 15:18:29.816 Dev[11794:809091] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5dae398'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x05b81494 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0563be02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x05b8b253 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x05ac089d ___forwarding___ + 1037
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x05ac046e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x0357acc6 -[UILabel _contentInsetsFromFonts] + 147
    6   UIKit                               0x03907ecc -[_UILabelLayer updateContentInsets] + 131
    7   UIKit                               0x03907fa1 -[_UILabelLayer updateContentLayerSize] + 48
    8   UIKit                               0x03908158 -[_UILabelLayer layoutSublayers] + 35
    9   QuartzCore                          0x030398b6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388
    10  QuartzCore                          0x030485b0 -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 44
    11  UIKit                               0x03377ba4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1258
    12  UIKit                               0x036aaa48 -[UITableViewCell _setFrame:skipLayout:] + 420
    13  UIKit                               0x036aa89f -[UITableViewCell setFrame:] + 63
    14  UIKit                               0x0343998d __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 4094
    15  UIKit                               0x0337ddb2 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
    16  UIKit                               0x0337ddfb +[UIView(Animation) _performWithoutAnimation:] + 40
    17  UIKit                               0x0343897c -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 504
    18  UIKit                               0x0344596b -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 877
    19  UIKit                               0x03445a7d -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 90
    20  UIKit                               0x03415b32 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3347
    21  UIKit                               0x03434416 __29-[UITableView layoutSubviews]_block_invoke + 52
    22  UIKit                               0x0344f6cc -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 88
    23  UIKit                               0x034342eb -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 214
    24  UIKit                               0x0338a3d4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 810
    25  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x05650059 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    26  QuartzCore                          0x03046096 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
    27  QuartzCore                          0x030398b6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388
    28  QuartzCore                          0x0303971a _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    29  QuartzCore                          0x0302bee7 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 317
    30  QuartzCore                          0x03060847 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 561
    31  QuartzCore                          0x03061108 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x05a9375e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x05a936be __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 398
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x05a8903c __CFRunLoopRun + 1340
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x05a88846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x05a8865b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x07149664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x071494a1 GSEventRun + 104
    39  UIKit                               0x032b9eb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
    40  Dev                           0x0015aaca main + 138
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x06067a25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Looks like one of your stings in the table views is NSNull. Since NSNull doesn't respond to -rangeOfCharacterFromSet: you got this exception. 
Check the data you pass to the tableview.

Comment: use fabric and crashlytics to trace crashes..

Comment: @VenoMKO I searched for rangeOfCharacterFromSet and find just one line in the code and when I debug I never get event to that method where I have rangeOfCharacterFromSet

Comment: Add the **po $arg1** command to your Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: `-rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` isn't send by you, but by Apple's code inside the table view *to* an object you provided. Therefore you will not find that in your code. Search for an instance of `NSNull` you deliver to the table view as suggested by @VenoMKO.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, cleaned derived data folder and now it works without that issue. But in any case it's strange that All exception does not show a line where a pp crashes.

I have a lot of NSNull, about 100 =) but need to be sure which table view delegate do I need to check. without additional info it's hard to find.

Comment: You shouldn't have hundreds of `NSNull`. This is a code smell, typically the selection of a wrong collection. However, the number of table view delegates should be not that big!? There cannot be a source code line, where the app crashes, because it crashes in Apple's code and you do not have the source code. If you have it, let me know. ;-)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, I understood it, I just support previous sources. but thank you for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode doesn't show a line of your code because none of your code is in that stack trace.  All of the frames are in the system frameworks (except, technically, main()).   This happens when you pass bad data to the system frameworks for whatever reason, in this case by passing bad data to a UILabel-- likely sticking an `NSNull` instance as the label's title.   This most often happens because of JSON parsing gone wrong (but it can happen for a variety of other reasons).

You need to harden your data processing code against unexpected values or unexpected structures.

Comment: yea agree, need to move project to Swift )